# putting iframe around proxy loaded page

Tags: proxy

i have a proxy site which loads extrenal sites into an iframe. i have a concern some sites will try to redirect out of the iframe when its detected. is this valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, redirection will only reload the iframe and not the whole page, if this was your question :)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it is, websites can detect being in an `iframe` and some would change the `parent` by javascript accordingly. However, simple HTTP redirection will only reload the iframe as Crimson said.